# Why do we ignore magnetic field vector during polarization?

Tags: visible-light, waves, polarization

Most light sources in nature emit unpolarized light. Natural light sources consist of very large number of randomly oriented atomic emitter, which emit polarized light randomly. A linear polarizer is a device whose input is light of any polarization state and output is linearly polarized light. Natural light can be represented by 2 independent orthogonally linearly polarized wave of the same amplitude,

$$E_{x}(t)=E_{0}sin(\omega t)$$
$$E_{g}(t)=E_{0}sin(\omega t+\varepsilon )$$

In this case, intensity =$E_{0}^{2}$ and each linearly polarized component contributes $\frac{(E_{0}^{2})}{2}$

My question is why is only **E** considered in polarization and not **B**.
Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well , when we linearly polarise (just for the sake of convenience ) an electromagnetic wave , both the electric and magnetic fields oscillate in a fixed direction , so we can say  that both the electric as well as the magnetic fields are  **polarised**.Obviously, a light ray cannot have its electric field oscillating in one direction and the  magnetic field just in a random direction. It's just a matter of choice and covenience. We have equipments that are better suited to measure the electric field as compared to the magnetic field so why talk of two different vectors when one is sufficient for all purposes ?